# Google Analytics Batch API to batch Google Analytics Core Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to use [batch api](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch) in python for batching [google analytics reporting api V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) calls I had already ran following command multiple times:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

But still getting error When running the below part of code:

```
service = build('farm', 'v2')
```

**ERROR:**
Exception has occurred: googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion name: farm version: v2

I believe i am missing some pip command to install the right python package.

Answer (score 0):

My bad I realized that below line of code was an example of creating your own object and through it, we need to call the new_batch_http_request().

```
    service = build('farm', 'v2')
```